# Wordpress ignores 'post_status' updates

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have two functions, `createNewsletter()`and `saveNewsletter($data)`. I get wrong `post_status` value on `wp_posts` table.

It seems to run adding `wp_publish_post( $data->id );` after the `wp_update_post`, but It's not clear to me why WP doesn't update the `post_status` while "enforcing" it with `wp_insert_post` or `wp_update_post` WP functions.

I noticed it runs removing `post_date`from the array definitions.

Here's my functions:

With the first one I put some data in an array in order to add it to db through a WP insert function:

```
$new_post = array(
    'post_title' => 'Newsletter del '.$date,
    'post_content' => "",
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_date' => current_time('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'post_author' => $loggedUser->ID,
    'post_type' => 'newsletter',
    'post_category' => array(0)
);

$post_ID = wp_insert_post($new_post);
```

With the second I want to save any modification to the newsletter and update the corrisponding fields:

```
$update_args = array(
    'ID' => $data->id,
    'post_title' => $data->properties->title,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'post_author' => $loggedUser->ID
);

$result = wp_update_post($update_args);
```

On both cases I'm expecting to get `post_status` = `publish` on the DB record, but I keep getting `post_status` = `future` after the execution of the first or the second function.

Comment: Maybe check the time zone setting on the system and make sure that your `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` call is returning the correct time. I believe `future` is set when the `post_date` is ... in the future.

Comment: Why are you adding a post_date?  Wordpress will automatically create the post and give it a publish date/time of when the post was created.  Unless you are needing a specific date and time, which it appears you do not, then you should just leave that out.  That will likely solve your problem.

Comment: I thought it was a good practice. I noticed it works without and it works as expected. Since I'm working on an existing project I wanted to edit only what is necessary.

Comment: @dazed-and-confused yes, you are right about `future` timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed not passing `post_date` can be the best option.

`future` was being set because the timestamp when I use `wp_insert_post($new_post);` uses `current_time()`, that is a future time (+2 hours from now).

Another option still valid is `wp_publish_post( $data->id );` that forces to set the `publish` status.